# How to auto-suggest class/function name in javascript live template?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, live-templates

In IntelliJ (or whatever variant) I am trying to make a "live template" to handle the boilerplate code when setting up PropTypes for React components.  If I have the function `Blink` and want to have proptypes set up for it, how can I have a live template where the `Blink` part of the line `Blink.propTypes` is auto suggested for me?  I'd like the IDE to guess at the name of that, but have it highlighted/selected so I can override it.  I'm stuck on the suggestion part though.

```
// Existing function
function Blink(props) {
  return (
      ...
  )
}

// Manually coded propTypes
Blink.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

//Simple live template, where I'd like the $NAME$ part to be smarter
$NAME$.propTypes = {
  $END$
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `jsClassName()` - seems to be a best choice here:

[image]

`classNameComplete()` also looks suitable

Comment: Thanks @lena.  Neither of them drop in the first suggestion class name automatically, but both offer a correctly filtered list of autocomplete options to quickly choose from (although I can't tell if that's just regular behavior).  `classNameComplete()` caused the autocomplete list to appear automatically, where `jsClassName()` required me to trigger it to show.  So, while the `jsClassName()` reads as being more appropriate, `classNameComplete()` comes closest to what I'm after.

Is there no option to automatically drop in the best guess without requiring me to do the autocomplete?

Comment: to me, `jsClassName()` auto-inserts `Blink` name when using your code snippet, allowing to choose other classes from completion list. This is the best option I can suggest.

Comment: Tried again and seems to be working now.  Must have messed something up on initial attempt.  Thanks!